# pandas, grouping data by week

Tags: pandas

There are approaximately 54 weeks in a year.

And I want to get sum of sales for each weak.

Given a time series data (with datetime or unixtime)
(my data looks like:

```
 userId,movieId,rating,timestamp
 1,31,2.5,1260759144
```

)

I want the output to look something like the following

```
1week (1/1 - 1/7) : 30$
2week (1/8 - 1/14) : 40$
...
54week (12/24 - 12/31) : 50$
```

The dates I put (`1/1` and so on) are just for explanation, I want to get weekly group (to get seasonal index), and it doesn't have to start from `1/1` or anything like that..

Data may contain multiple years.

- Edit

I want to do group-by week over multiple years, like you could do group-by monthly [jan, feb, ..... dec] over multiple years (12 groups for multi-year data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html) by `week` and aggregate function - e.g.by `mean`:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10)
s = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10)},index=rng)['a']
print (s)
2017-04-03    0
2017-04-04    1
2017-04-05    2
2017-04-06    3
2017-04-07    4
2017-04-08    5
2017-04-09    6
2017-04-10    7
2017-04-11    8
2017-04-12    9
Freq: D, Name: a, dtype: int64

s1 = s.resample('W').mean()
#alternative
#s1 = s.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W')).mean()
print (s1)
2017-04-09    3
2017-04-16    8
Freq: W-SUN, Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Alternative:

```
s1 = s.groupby(s.index.strftime('%Y-%U')).mean()
print (s1)
2017-14    2.5
2017-15    7.5
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

EDIT:

With sample data need preprocessing:

```
print (df)
   userId  movieId  rating   timestamp
0       1       31     2.5  1260759144
1       1       31     2.5  1560759144


df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s')

w = df['timestamp'].rename('week').dt.weekofyear
df = df['rating'].groupby(w).mean().reset_index(name='val')
print (df)
   week  val
0    25  2.5
1    51  2.5
```

Comment: Thanks!, I haven't used DatetimeIndex before, (I added how my data look like to op) and trying to decypher how I could apply it..

And, if data contains 2017 and 2018 data, does it group first week of year as one group?

Comment: @eugene - so, I think DatetimeIndex,because in title is `timeseries` :)

Comment: @eugene - So it depends - My experience is `resample` should be more accurate,but also added alternative solution - converting `DatetimeIndex` to strings by [strftime](http://strftime.org/).The best compare both solutions.

Comment: can you enlighten me how I can apply your method with my data format ? :( I'm sure it would solve my problem , but it will take me some time to follow what's happening

Comment: @eugene - Can you check data sample ?

Comment: yeah I did `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s') ;df.resample('w', on='date').mean()` thanks! .. one thing is it seems, it doesn't seem to deal with multi year, data, so I need to do work on it after doing `resample`

Comment: @eugene - What do you think `multiyear` ? years are not necessary in output?

Comment: Say you want to get monthly seasonal index, and your data has more than one year of data. I could get monthly seasonal index per every year, and then average it. I thought I might just do it in one step and get monthly seasonal index for multiple years data.

Comment: @eugene - So it seems more complicated, you need convert DattimeIndex or datetime column to seasonal like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25647546/2901002) ?

Comment: yeah, he's grouping multiple years data by `'DJF', 'MAM', 'JJA', 'SON'` .. I want to do similar thing with `week`

Comment: oh yeah, data format looks good, although I'll have to look up doc a bit to see what it's going on :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a week column first, to_datetime from `pandas` is really useful

```
df['week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.week
df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).dt.year
weekly_sales = df.groupby(['year','week'])['sales'].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for help! but df['week'] seems to be 1 for every row for some reason

Comment: @eugene it is hard to tell without the timestamps, the dates change yeah?